# Summary of raster values ​for a region

Tags: qgis, raster, r, table

I'm stuck with a problem:

I got three raster's layers: "Sand", "Clay" and "BD" (Bulk density) of the same region.

How can I obtain a "table" or a "Data frame" with information for the values of the raster's for each pixel?

I prefer to use QGIS or R.

My main goal is to obtain a lookuptable of this features of the soil:

[image]

So i will merge pixels with the same information for Clay, Sand and BD into a unique MU_GLOBAL index.

Comment: Can you describe a bit more in detail how it looks what you want? Can you give an example? You might want to have a look at raster attribute table plugin (experimental version as of now): https://twitter.com/elpaso66/status/1393105641334579201 and here https://youtu.be/r-9_jgBFHsE

Comment: @babel, i will give it a try. Also i have edited the question! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need to calculate the values of the **entire extent of the raster**?

if so in QGIS is very easy and fast, you can use expressions and get the global statistics of your raster in a table.

1. Create a temporary layer, not geometry. Or create a dbf table
2. In the toolbar there is a button that allows you to add a record.
3. Open the field calculator, then go to the expressions in the raster option, you will find two options: statistics and value.

We will use the statistics, you can calculate the value:

- max: maximum
- min: minimum
- avg: average
- stdev: standard deviation
- range: range
- sum: sum

An example calculating the **average**, give a name to the field, define a decimal number, with two or more decimals.

4. Write and execute the expression:

`raster_statistic('BASIN001D8',1,'avg')`

In this case, 'CUENCA001D8' is the **name of the layer** as it appears in the layers panel.
The value 1 **is the band** of the raster layer being queried.

Answer (score 3):

Using R, you could do something like:

```
# Assuming the raster layers are geotiff format
library(raster)
rast_list = c(""Sand.tif", "Clay.tif", "BD.tif")
soil_stack = stack(rast_list)
soil_values_df = values(soil_stack)
```

Although, depending on the size of your region, and resolution, this could be quite inefficient. Not sure what MU_GLOBAL refers to.

Comment: Hey Micha! 
MU_GLOBAL refers to equal combinations between sand, clay and bd!